# Assert number of items in Include with wildcard

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C# project where I need to include a file as a resource. I don't know the full name of the file in advance, as it will include a version number that I can't easily access at build time. So I'm using a wildcard like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\setup\bin\MyApp-setup-*.exe">
      <Link>Setup\%(filename)%(extension)</Link>
      <LogicalName>Setup\%(filename)%(extension)</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

It works, but the problem is that it can include any number of files, and I want it to include exactly one. There should be only one matching file in the folder. If there are zero or several files that match the wildcard, I want it to be a build error. Is there a way to assert that only one file is included?

---

EDIT: Thanks to @stijn's answer, I was able to do it like this:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\setup\bin\MyApp-setup-*.exe">
        <Link>AppFiles\%(filename)%(extension)</Link>
        <LogicalName>AppFiles\%(filename)%(extension)</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SetupFileCount>@(EmbeddedResource->Count())</SetupFileCount>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Text="Expected exactly one file matching 'MyApp-setup-*'; found $(SetupFileCount)." Condition="'$(SetupFileCount)' != '1'"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: have you tried with the ? wild card MyApp-setup-?

Comment: @Zinov `?` just matches one character. I could do `MyApp-setup-?.?.?.?`, but it could still match several files.

Comment: I am confused here, you said you don't know the full name of the file in advance(means you only can resolve it in runtime no?) and then you want  it to be a build error. Can you explain better your approach? Is not MyApp-setup-# where # the version number?, but still there, you will get more than one match

Comment: @Zinov the file I'm trying to include is generated during a prior build step. I don't know what its exact name will be, because I don't know it's version. If the prior build step didn't clean the directory before creating the new file, it might contain older files, which I don't want to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Item Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886422.aspx) 'Count' to get the number of items and raise an error if it's not 1:

```
<Target Name="ErrorIfNotOneEmbeddedResourceFound" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\setup\bin\MyApp-setup-*.exe">
      <Link>Setup\%(filename)%(extension)</Link>
      <LogicalName>Setup\%(filename)%(extension)</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Error Text="Didn't find one match" Condition="'@(EmbeddedResource->Count())' != '1'"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: As an alternative you could find all matches, then analyze the version number to find the highest one, or considering created date or so, assuming that is what you're after. But that is more complicated and if it won't happen often just raising an error is better imo.

Comment: Not sure why, but I couldn't get this target to run before `Build`; it was actually running *after* `CoreBuild`, so the resource was not included. I eventually put the tasks in the `BeforeBuild` target. Now it works fine, thanks!

Comment: I didn't test at what stage it runs exactly. I've used BeforeTargets="BuildGenerateSources" as well in the past, I think that's before CoreBuild.